# How to create groups of table rows with alternating colors?

Tags: tables, macros, grouping

**Problem.** When coloring a table, using different colors for even / odd rows is quite usual and can be accomplished with the [`xcolor`](http://www.bitlib.net/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf) package. I, however, don't want to have alternating colors per row, but per *row group*.

**Example.** The following example is minimal working. I have a macro `\writerow` to output a table row (because much information in the original file is automatically generated), and I have a second macro `\setgroup` to set the group to `1` (white background) or `2` (gray background). To store this information, there is a macro `\rc` (reading "row color").

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

%
% Macros

\newcommand\rc{0.8}
\newcommand\setgroup[1]{
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{
                \renewcommand\rc{1.0}
        }{
                \renewcommand\rc{0.8}
        }
}
\newcommand\writerow[1]{
        \\ \rowcolor[gray]{\rc} #1
}

%
% Data

\begin{tabular}{l}
\textbf{Header}
        \setgroup{1}
                \writerow{Zeile 1}
                \writerow{Zeile 2}
        \setgroup{2}
                \writerow{Zeile 3}
                \writerow{Zeile 4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Presumptions.** The example works; however, every row is colored gray, which means that the `\renewcommand\rc` isn't working. Why?

Probably it's a problem of scope. But the only scope I can see in that document is that of the `tabular` environment, which shouldn't be a problem, as all the operations happen inside of it.

Where is my error? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Each _cell_ of a table is a scope, so you need to make your commands global. use `\gdef` rather than `\renewcommand`

Comment: Hey @David, thanks for your comment. That works like a charm! If you don't want to post this as a solution, I'll do so as soon as I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each cell of a table is a scope, so you need to make your commands global. use `\gdef` rather than `\renewcommand` as LaTeX doesn't offer a LaTeX-interface to global settings.

Comment: Does LaTeX3 have an interface for global settings?

Comment: @MartinSchröder `\cs_new:Npn` is possibly the nearest thing at the code level to this. (with some help in chat from @egreg and @JosephWright)