# Color alternating groups (5) of rows in Table gray and white

Tags: tables, booktabs, rowcolor

I am trying to color every other grouping of 5 rows light gray, starting with the first 5 rows.
I have attempted to use the solution posted here [Does something like \rowcolors exist for groups of rows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395945/does-something-like-rowcolors-exist-for-groups-of-rows)
. However, there are several problems. My original (uncolored; see below) looks great. However, when I try to color the rows (see below) the pdf looks terrible with missing rows and the printed version starts 1 row to late ( i.e., the first 5 line should be gray). So in summary I would like the pdf to look as nice as the printed and have the coloring start 1 row sooner. I have attached compilable code to reproduce the document and images of the output on my end below.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside, notitlepage]{article}% calls document type
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, table, xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}% table utilities
\usepackage{siunitx}% number and symbol alignment
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\VRule[1][\arrayrulewidth]{\vrule width #1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\groupedRowColors}[5][0]{% [#1: offset], #2: group size, #3: start line, #4: color 1, #5: color 2
% copied from xcolor.sty
\global\rownum=\z@
\global\@rowcolorstrue
\@ifxempty{#4}%
    {\def\@oddrowcolor{\@norowcolor}}%
    {\def\@oddrowcolor{\gdef\CT@row@color{\CT@color{#4}}}}%
\@ifxempty{#5}%
    {\def\@evenrowcolor{\@norowcolor}}%
    {\def\@evenrowcolor{\gdef\CT@row@color{\CT@color{#5}}}}%
% simplified (no check for \if@rowcmd)
\def\@rowcolors{%
    \if@rowcolors
        \noalign{%
            \relax
            \ifnum\rownum<#3
                \@norowcolor
            % I have changed this check:
            \else \ifodd \numexpr (\rownum-#1)/#2\relax
                \@oddrowcolor
            \else
                \@evenrowcolor
            \fi \fi
        }%
    \fi
}%
\CT@everycr{\@rowc@lors\the\everycr}%
\ignorespaces
 }
\makeatother

\usepackage[letterpaper,bindingoffset=-.35in,%
left=1in,right=1in,top=.25in,bottom=.25in,%
footskip=.15in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\belowrulesep=0pt
\aboverulesep=0pt
\heavyrulewidth=2pt

\begin{table}[t!]
\begin{tabular}[l]{|p{.6in}|p{2.46in}|p{1in}|p{2.46in}| }
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{}\\
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{\textbf{Date}\rule{.8in}{.1pt} \hspace{.69in} \textbf{Crew}\rule{2.4in}{.1pt}\hspace{1.2in} \textbf{Page}\rule{.2in}{.1pt}  \textbf{of}\rule{.25in}{.1pt}} \\
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{}\\
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{\textbf{Species}\rule{.95in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Location}\rule{.95in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Project}\rule{.95in}{.1pt}}\\
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\vspace*{-2.75\baselineskip}
\begin{centering}
\begin{table}[bh!]
\groupedRowColors{5}{1}{gray!20}{white} %<------line that is supposed to color by group
\begin{tabular}{!{\VRule[2pt]}p{.6in}|p{2.46in}|p{1in}|p{2.46in}!{\VRule[2pt]}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Count} & \textbf{PIT Tag \#} & \textbf{Length(TL)} & \textbf{Comments}\\
    \bottomrule
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\


\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{\textbf{Scanned}\rule{.6in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Entered}\rule{.6in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Checked}\rule{.6in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Double Checked}\rule{.6in}{.1pt}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{centering}
\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}
\small\textit{\textbf{*} Max 40 fish per sheet}\hspace{.5in}\textbf{Notes:}

\end{document}
```

**This is what the original pdf looks like without coloring:**

[image: original data sheet]

**This is what it looks like after I apply the solution:**

*PDF*

[image: bad pdf]

*Printed*
[image: bad printed]

Comment: Regarding the missing lines in the pdf: This is most likely a viewer issue. If I compile your code and open the pdf I recieve the following result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRayl.png

Comment: Okay, wierd I'm using Adobe acrobat reader DC latest version. What pdf reader are you using

Comment: The lines will get visible if you zoom in. More information can be found here: [Adobe Reader and xcolor within a table breaks the line render](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53935/134144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the fixed code to solve the problem above:**

**This line fixes were row coloring starts**

```
\groupedRowColors{5}{-1}{gray!15}{white}%<------- starts coloring at first row
```

**This line makes is so row lines are visible in adobe reader**

```
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.7pt}% <------- fixes so lines can be viewed in adobe reader
```

**Full code:**

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside, notitlepage]{article}% calls document type
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, table, xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}% table utilities
\usepackage{siunitx}% number and symbol alignment
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.7pt}% <------- fixes so lines can be viewed in adobe reader
\newcommand\VRule[1][\arrayrulewidth]{\vrule width #1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\groupedRowColors}[5][0]{% [#1: offset], #2: group size, #3: start line, #4: color 1, #5: color 2
% copied from xcolor.sty
\global\rownum=\z@
\global\@rowcolorstrue
\@ifxempty{#4}%
    {\def\@oddrowcolor{\@norowcolor}}%
    {\def\@oddrowcolor{\gdef\CT@row@color{\CT@color{#4}}}}%
\@ifxempty{#5}%
    {\def\@evenrowcolor{\@norowcolor}}%
    {\def\@evenrowcolor{\gdef\CT@row@color{\CT@color{#5}}}}%
% simplified (no check for \if@rowcmd)
\def\@rowcolors{%
    \if@rowcolors
        \noalign{%
            \relax
            \ifnum\rownum<#3
                \@norowcolor
            % I have changed this check:
            \else \ifodd \numexpr (\rownum-#1)/#2\relax
                \@oddrowcolor
            \else
                \@evenrowcolor
            \fi \fi
        }%
    \fi
}%
\CT@everycr{\@rowc@lors\the\everycr}%
\ignorespaces
 }
\makeatother

\usepackage[letterpaper,bindingoffset=-.35in,%
left=1in,right=1in,top=.25in,bottom=.25in,%
footskip=.15in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\belowrulesep=0pt
\aboverulesep=0pt
\heavyrulewidth=2pt

\begin{table}[t!]
\begin{tabular}[l]{|p{.6in}|p{2.46in}|p{1in}|p{2.46in}| }
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{}\\
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{\textbf{Date}\rule{.8in}{.1pt} \hspace{.69in} \textbf{Crew}\rule{2.4in}{.1pt}\hspace{1.2in} \textbf{Page}\rule{.2in}{.1pt}  \textbf{of}\rule{.25in}{.1pt}} \\
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{}\\
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{\textbf{Species}\rule{.95in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Location}\rule{.95in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Project}\rule{.95in}{.1pt}}\\
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\vspace*{-2.75\baselineskip}
\begin{centering}
\begin{table}[bh!]
\groupedRowColors{5}{-1}{gray!15}{white}%<------- starts coloring at first row
\begin{tabular}{!{\VRule[2pt]}p{.6in}|p{2.46in}|p{1in}|p{2.46in}!{\VRule[2pt]}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Count} & \textbf{PIT Tag \#} & \textbf{Length(TL)} & \textbf{Comments}\\
    \bottomrule
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & \\


\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{\textbf{Scanned}\rule{.6in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Entered}\rule{.6in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Checked}\rule{.6in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Double Checked}\rule{.6in}{.1pt}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{centering}
\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}
\small\textit{\textbf{*} Max 40 fish per sheet}\hspace{.5in}\textbf{Notes:}
\end{document}
```